# PHPでCometを実装したとき、たまにデータを出力しない

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

## やっていること

PHPでCometによるチャットシステムを作成しています。
// このご時世になんでWebSocketを使わないんだ？ という話はなしでお願いします。
概ねはうまく動くのですが、時々PHPが情報を吐き出してくれないことがあり、どうにかならないかお尋ねしたいです。

## 構造

ページは**input.html**, **output.html**, **comet.php**, **chat.txt**, **filesize.txt**の5枚構成です。

1. **output.html**が**comet.php**をajax通信で呼び出しロングポーリング
2. **input.html**でチャット文章を入力し**chat.txt**に保存
3. **comet.php**内で**chat.txt**のファイルサイズを監視し、ファイルサイズが大きくなったらチャットに新しい文が入力されたと判断
4. **comet.php**で新しく入力された**chat.txt**の内容を取得し、**output.html**に渡す
5. **output.html**がチャットの内容を受け取り、画面に出力する

という動きを取ります。

基本的に**input.html**に多人数がアクセスし、**output.html**には1人がアクセスする、という想定です。
// 今回、input.htmlは関係しないものと思うのでこれ以降出てきませんが、もし解決の可能性がinput.htmlにあるようでしたらまた追記します。

## コード

**output.html**内の`func()`関数内でJavaScript（jQuery）によるajax通信を実行し、**comet.php**でロングポーリングしながら（という言い方が正しいかわかりませんが）、チャットの更新があった場合に表示します。

<output.html>

```html
<script>
    function func() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comet.php",
            chche: false,
            data: { 'hoge': fuga },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (d) {
           console.log('received');  // (★)
           // 表示処理
           func();  // 再帰呼び出しで実質無限ループ
        }
        ).fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, status, e) {
            // エラー処理
        });
    }
    
    $(function () {
       func();
    });
</script>
```

<comet.php>

```php
$time = 0;
$oldfs = 0;
$newfs = 0;
$result = "{}";  // 最終的にこの変数が output.html に渡されます

while($time < 30) {  // 30秒経ったらループを抜ける
    clearstatcache();
        
    $oldfs = file_get_contents('filesize.txt');  // (1) 以前のファイルサイズ
    $newfs = filesize('chat.txt');  // (2) 現在のファイルサイズ

    if($oldfs < $newfs) {  // 現在のファイルサイズが以前より大きい ＝ チャットに新しく書き込まれた
        file_put_contents('filesize.txt', $newfs, LOCK_EX);  // (3) 現在のファイルサイズで以前のファイルサイズを上書き
        $result = json_encode(piyo);
        echo $result;  // (4) output.htmlにデータ受け渡し
        return false;
    }
    sleep(1);  // 負荷軽減
    $time++;
}

echo $result;  // 30秒経って何も更新がなかったら一度output.htmlに更新がなかったことを伝える
return false;
```

**comet.php**の動きについて補足します。

- (1) では、以前の更新時に使っていた、**chat.txt**のファイルサイズを取得（初期値は0）します。
- (2) では、現在の**chat.txt**のファイルサイズを取得（初期値は0）します。
- (3) は現在のファイルサイズ`$newfs`が、以前のファイルサイズ`$oldfs`を上回っていたときに、以前のファイルサイズを保存するファイル**filesize.txt**を現在のファイルサイズで上書きします。この値が、次の走査のときの`$oldfs`に代入されます。
- (4) のecho文で、`$result`の内容が**output.html**に返されます。この`$result`は、`piyo`という配列をjson形式にしたものです。
- 30秒経ったときにwhile文を抜けるようにしているのはconnection lostを回避するためです（これが正しいのか、そもそも必要なのか特に調べていませんが……）

## 問題点（解決したいこと）

**input.html**からチャットの入力があったとき、**comet.php**のコード(4)部分でその内容が**output.html**に渡され画面に出力される、というのが想定ですが、これがたまに動かなくなり、**input.html**での入力が**output.html**に表示されなくなります。

原因が分からず、できるだけ切り分けを行ってみたのですが、この問題が起きたとき、

- **chat.txt**には間違いなく入力された文章が保存されている
- **comet.php**のコード(3)部分で、ファイルサイズは最新のものに間違いなく更新され、**filesize.txt**に保存されている
- **output.html** のコード(★)部分で、`console.log('received');`が動いていない
- **output.html** の`$.ajax`内で、`.fail`によるエラー処理は発生していない
- この問題が生じたあと、新しい文章がチャットに入力されると、それは表示されるときもあるし表示されないときもある

ということは把握しています。
この問題が発生するのは、チャットの全入力数に対して体感2割くらいの確率です。

この切り分けが本当に正しく行われているのであれば、問題は**comet.php**内の
`$result = json_encode(piyo);`か、その直後の`echo $result;`、
もしくは**output.html**内の`$.ajax`内で問題が発生していることになります。

しかし「絶対に動かないわけではなく、たまに動かなくなる」という状況ゆえ、決定的な原因を突き止めることが出来ておらず、途方に暮れています。

この問題を解決する方法について、皆様のお力添えをいただきたいです。

## 環境

PHPのバージョンは7.4.21および7.4.28です。両方で同じ問題が発生しています。

## さいごに

こういうサイトで質問することに慣れていないため、不躾な点ありましたらご容赦ください。また不足している情報がありましたら追記させていただきます。
皆様のお力添えを、どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: Chromeのdevtool等をつかい、ネットワークの状況を見てみると間違いなく通信は行われていますか？そして通信が終わってもdoneには入ってこないということですか？

Comment: if($oldfs < $newfs) { て文字列と文字数を比較しているのは？ですが、filesize関数はキャッシュされます。https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.filesize.php 注意を参照のこと

Comment: @yyz さん   
> if($oldfs < $newfs) { て文字列と文字数を比較しているのは？   
filesize.txtの拡張子がミスリーディングを誘っているかもしれませんが、filesize.txt(=$oldfs)にはファイルサイズを示す数値しか記録されていませんので、$oldfsと$newfsは数値どうしの比較をしています。   
   
> filesize関数はキャッシュされます。   
説明には加えていませんでしたが、comet.phpのwhile内でclearstatcache();を実行しています。これでキャッシュ問題は解決したと考えていますが、不足している部分はありますか？

Comment: @keitaro_so さん  
> Chromeのdevtool等をつかい、ネットワークの状況を見てみると間違いなく通信は行われていますか？そして通信が終わってもdoneには入ってこないということですか？  
確認しました。通常の動作ですと、ロングポーリングを行っているときはcomet.phpのStatusがpendingになり、チャットへの新しい入力を検知したら200が返され、再び新しいcomet.phpの通信がpendingの状態で停止します。しかし上記の問題が発生した場合は当該通信のcomet.phpはpendingのまま変化しません。つまりdoneにもfailにも分岐していないと推察されます。

Comment: php:最大実行時間の設定により強制終了しているかもしれないので、ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);を設定してどうなるか確認 または、whileをやめてjsからの一定間隔の呼び出しに変える。js側:関数の無限再帰呼び出しではなく、タイマーによる繰り返し呼び出しにした方が良いと思います。（無限のメモリーがあるなら再帰呼び出しでも良いが）

Comment: @yyz さん > php:最大実行時間の設定により強制終了しているかもしれないので、ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);を設定してどうなるか確認  
設定はのちほど確認しますが、短時間の間でも当該問題が発生すること、長時間でも当該問題が発生しないことがあること、少なくとも同じif文内にある(3)が実行されていることを踏まえると強制終了の線は極めて薄いと考えます。  
> whileをやめてjsからの一定間隔の呼び出しに変える。js側:関数の無限再帰呼び出しではなく、タイマーによる繰り返し呼び出しにした方が良い  
これはサーバ負荷の観点から避けたい方法です。極力リアルタイム性を確保したいということもありこのような実装にしています。  
  
コメントありがとうございます。

Comment: もしかしたら、同じタブで同時にたくさんロングボーリングしていたりしないですか？

Comment: @keitaro_so さん
> もしかしたら、同じタブで同時にたくさんロングボーリングしていたりしないですか？
ということも無いですね……